# Is there a hypernym for "horizontal" and "vertical"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, hypernyms

If I want to speak of *North, South, East, West* in a general sense I could, for example, use the term *cardinal direction*.

Which term is appropriate to sum up *horizontal* and *vertical* in the same manner?

Comment: Can you add more context please? *Orientation*, *direction*, *extension*, and others could or could not work depending on context.

Comment: @ЯegDwight, thanks for editing. I have objects that are able to move vertically or horizontally within a plane area. I want to *remember* the status for the current moving object. Since the only states will be horizontal and vertical I need a name which generalizes those two words. I will go for *axis* or *commonaxis* in this case, as suggested by Joel Brown in his answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the context, you might use **axis** or **orientation** (*credit: RegDwight*).